# How to prevent a client race condition between Meteor.userId() and subscription updates that depend on userId?

Tags: meteor

I am seeing a repeatable issue where a user authenticates ("logs in") with a Meteor server, and then a client subscription that depends on `userId` is updated (and dependent UI templates reactively update) ***before*** `Meteor.userId()` registers the successful login.

For example, in this code snippet, the assert will `throw`:

```
var coll = new Meteor.Collection("test");

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('mineOrPublic', function () {
        // Publish public records and those owned by subscribing user
        return coll.find({owner: { $in: [ this.userId, null ]}});
    });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    var sub = Meteor.subscribe('mineOrPublic');
    var cursor = coll.find({});
    cursor.observe({
        added: function (doc) {
            if (doc.owner) {
                // This should always be true?!
                assert(doc.owner === Meteor.userId());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Analogous to the `added` function above, if I write a template helper that checks `Meteor.userId()`, it will see a value of `null`, even when it is invoked with a data context of a document with an owner.

There is apparently a race condition between Meteor collection Pub/Sub and the Account `userId` update mechanisms. It seems to me that `Meteor.userId()` should always be updated *before* any subscriptions update based on a change in `this.userId` in a server publish function, but for some reason the opposite usually seems to be true (that is, the `assert` in the code above will usually throw).

The reason I care is because I have packages that depend on obtaining a valid Meteor Authentication token (using `Accounts._storedLoginToken()`) on the client for use in securing HTTP requests for files stored on the Meteor server. And the authentication token isn't correct until `Meteor.userId()` is. So the flow of events usually goes something like this:

- User logs in
- Publish function on server reruns based on the change in `this.userId`.
- Client begins receiving new documents corresponding to the change in userId.
- UI Template reactively updates to add DOM elements driven by new documents
- Some of the DOM elements are `<img>` tags with `src=` values that depend on the data context.
- HTTP requests are triggered and ultimately fail with `403` (forbidden) errors because the required authentication cookie hasn't been set yet.
- `Meteor.userId()` finally updates on the client, and code reactively runs to set the authentication cookie
- Helpers in the template that depend on a session variable set in the cookie update code are rerun, but the DOM doesn't change, because the URLs in the `<img>` tags don't change.
- Because the DOM doesn't change, the  tags don't retry their failed attempts to load the images.
- Everything settles down, and the user has to manually reload the page to get their images to appear.

I've come up with two possible approaches to work around this issue:

1. In the template helper that generates the URL for the `<img>` tag, always append a dummy query string such as: `"?time=" + new Date().getTime()`. This causes the DOM to change every time the helper is called and fixes the problem, but it screws-up browser caching and if not coordinated will cause some assets to unnecessarily load multiple times, etc.
2. In every template helper that touches document data add a test of:

   ```
   if (this.owner && this.owner !== Meteor.userId()) { 
      // Perhaps Meteor.loggingIn() could be used above?
      // Invalid state, output placeholder
   } else {
      // Valid state, output proper value for template
   }
   ```

I really hope someone knows of a less kludgy way to work around this. Alternatively, if consensus arises that this is a bug and Meteor's behavior is incorrect in this respect. I will happily file an issue on Github. I mostly really enjoy working with Meteor, but this is the kind of gritty annoyance that grinds in the gears of "it just works".

Thanks for any and all insights.

Comment: Have you tried checking Meteor.userId() before calling subscribe() on the client?

Comment: That doesn't really help my situation, because the subscription may contain valid "public" documents that unauthenticated users can see, and that remain when a user authenticates. Your question suggests another alternative I hadn't considered though: I suppose another way to handle this would be to use the reactivity of `Meteor.userId()` to `.stop()` the subscription and then create a new one, but I'm concerned that could add a lot of latency, and would lead to many documents being sent twice.

Comment: Stop and rerun within autorun() does not remove docs and resend.  Meteor is smarter than that.  See docs on [subscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe).

Comment: By 'client subscription', do you mean a publication function or an actual `Meteor.subscribe` on the client that runs in a reactive computation depending on `Meteor.userId()`?

Comment: By 'client subscription' I mean the contents of a collection on the client that update automatically based on a subscription to a server publication.

Comment: On stop and rerun within `autorun()`: Correct, so that approach won't solve this issue at all, because the new documents will still arrive too early, and then they won't be removed and update. In any case, doing something based on the contents of `Meteor.userId()` can't help because it is updating much later than the record set is updating.

Comment: I just edited the question to add a code snippet to hopefully be completely clear about what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying lots of things, this variation on the example code in the OP seems to consistently solve the race condition, and I find this an acceptable resolution, unlike my initial attempted workarounds.

I still feel that this kind of logic should be unnecessary and welcome other approaches or opinions on whether Meteor's behavior in the OP sample code is correct or erroneous. If consensus emerges in the comments that Meteor's behavior is wrong, I will create an issue on Github for this.

Thanks for any additional feedback or alternative solutions.

```
var coll = new Meteor.Collection("test");

if (Meteor.isServer) {

    Meteor.publish('mineOrPublic', function (clientUserId) {
        if (this.userId === clientUserId) {
            // Publish public records and those owned by subscribing user
            return coll.find({owner: { $in: [ this.userId, null ]}});
        } else {
            // Don't return user owned docs unless client sub matches
            return coll.find({owner: null});
        }
    });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Deps.autorun(function () {
        // Resubscribe anytime userId changes
        var sub = Meteor.subscribe('mineOrPublic', Meteor.userId());
    });

    var cursor = coll.find({});

    cursor.observe({
        added: function (doc) {
            if (doc.owner) {
                // This should always be true?!
                assert(doc.owner === Meteor.userId());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This code works by giving the server publish function the information it needs to recognize when it is running ahead of the client's own login state, thereby breaking the race condition.

I think this is something that Meteor should do automatically: clients should not see documents based on changes to `this.userId` in a publish function until after the client `Meteor.userId()` has been updated.

Do others agree?

Answer (score -1):

I tried with this code that works on server too. In association with FileCollection package.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  CurrentUserId = null;
  Meteor.publish(null, function() {
    CurrentUserId = this.userId;
  });
}

....
OrgFiles.allow({
  read: function (userId, file) {
     if (CurrentUserId !== file.metadata.owner) {
       return false;
     } else {
       return true;
     }
  }
 ...
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the original question?